# php how to check a string for more than 5 consonants in a row

Tags: php, spam

As a spam filter I want to block any comments that contain

> djgalkgjlkdg

or any other excessive amount of consonants in a row.

I thought of maybe having an array of consonants and then check the comment with it, but seems too long and cumbersome.

Do you know of any way I can do this without guzzling memory?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`preg_match('/[bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxz]{6}/i', $input)` perhaps?

Comment: But more correct. The question was about "more than 5" though, so it should be `{6}`. For example, there is a slovak word with 5 consonants in a row "zmrzlina". :)

Answer (score 3):

```
if(preg_match("~[bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz]{4,}~", $string)......
```

Comment: I would add an `i` after the pattern to make it case-insensitive.

Answer (score 0):

Matches any alphabetic character but numbers:

`/i` at the end makes it case insensitive.

```
$find = '/([b-df-hj-np-tv-z]{4})/i';
if(preg_match($find,$comment)){
   //spam filter action
}
```